# WebApi PUT does not work when the method has variables MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, soap, asp.net-web-api, webmethod

I'm new to WebApi and the tutorial was going well.  I got Get, Get with variables, Post, and Delete to work, but I can't seem to get Put to work.  Well, if I remove all the variables from the method the in the controller, it actually goes into the method, but that's pretty useless.  Has anyone come across this before that knows how to fix it?

PUT Url sent to Postman:

```
http://localhost:60679/api/incident/1234
```

Preview:

```
PUT /api/incident/1234 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60679
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Error Message:

```
 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI     
'http://localhost:60679/api/incident/1234'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the      
controller 'Incident' that matches the request."}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApiTest.AppLogic;
using WebApiTest.Data.Core;

namespace WebApiTest.WebApi.Controllers
{
public class IncidentController : ApiController
{


    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<Incident> Get()
    {
        using (EntityDemoEntities context = new EntityDemoEntities())
        {
            return context.Incidents.ToList<Incident>();
        }
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public Incident Get(string id)
    {
        using (EntityDemoEntities context = new EntityDemoEntities())
        {
            Guid tempGuid = new Guid(id);
            return context.Incidents.SingleOrDefault(i => i.IncidentId == tempGuid);
        }
    }


    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut]
    public void Put(string guid)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Do something
            }
            else
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid Model");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException == null ? String.Empty : ex.InnerException.Message, ex.InnerException == null ? String.Empty : ex.InnerException.StackTrace));
        }
    }
}
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name ="WebDAVModule"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name='WebDAVModule'/>
</modules>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your routing table.  Have you declared all of the necessary parameters in the appropriate route definition?

Comment: Robert - See Kiran's answer below you are correct, the parameter names were not matching, causing the issue (guid != id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your action to `Put(string id)` or `Put([FromUri(Name="id")]string guid)`